# Getting a div's information when I mouse over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to mouse over a `<div>` and use JavaScript to get the information (for example the `id`) and store it in a variable.

What would be the most efficient way to make this happen?

Comment: you mean its innerHTML ?

Comment: `<div>` elements do not have a "value" in normal parlance.  What is it about the elements that you want to retrieve?

Comment: what would it set TO? the name/id of the div? something other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sould do it for you :

```
$('div').mouseover(function(){
   var content = $(this).html();
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   alert('the element\'s ID is: '+id+'and content is: '+content);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#yourDivId').hover(function(){
  var value = $(this).html();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var currentDivID;
var currentDivValue;
$(document).ready(function(){

$('div').mouseover(function(){
  currentDivID = this.id
  currentDivValue = $(this).html();
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

besides the fact that div's doesn't have values, you can store it's text or argument or something else.

```
var someVar = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').mouseover(function(){
        someVar = $('div').html();
        someVar = $('div').attr('id');
        someVar = $('div').attr('class');
        someVar = $('div').find('input').val();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div").bind("mouseenter",function(){

var divHTML = $(this).html();

});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fveRk/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example:

```
<div id="test">Hello world!</div>

$('#test').mouseover(function(){
    var test = $(this);
    console.log(test);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4uLzf/

Answer (score 0):

Attach a mouseover event to the div.

Using jquery:

```
$('#theDiv').mouseover(function() {
    var value = $(this).html();
    //store value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a nice way to detect the hovering: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

When you say "get the value" are you talking about getting the div's contents? In that case, the html() jQuery method will do it.

http://api.jquery.com/html/